# How to reference a different spreadsheet in HLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I try to reference another spreadsheet in the HLOOKUP formula but fail. I'm doing this like:

`=HLOOKUP(A2,"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOzV/","report!A2:B2",2,0)`

where `http...` is the URL of another spreadsheet, `report!...` is the name of the tab in another spreadsheet and the data range.

This kind of referencing of another spreadsheet's URL works with `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOzV/","report!A2:B2")`, as I realized from different examples.

But with `HLOOKUP` while doing so I get an error:

`Wrong number of arguments to HLOOKUP. Expected between 3 and 4 arguments, but got 5 arguments.`

It seems, that the spreadsheet URL is counted as separate parameter.

How do I correctly reference **the URL, the sheet name and the data range**?

**PS**: I tried to chain `HLOOKUP` and `importrange`, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39305031/1992004 - but fail on it, got just `#REF`.

My formula was

`=HLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOzV"; "report!$A$2:$B$2"),2,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are searching the content of cell A2 against imported range A2:B2 and if the match is found you returning the 1st row (of the whole dataset) of imported range after match eg. that's cell B2 of `report!$A$2:$B$2`. in other words range A2:B2 is one row so you cant return 2nd row from the one-row matrix, therefore valid formula is:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2,IMPORTRANGE("1I69LQ37hA5NjjJmuwmWkrDI_daiU_cnYDrUBpMm","report!$A$2:$B$2"),1,0)
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do hookup from different spreadsheet - by importrange? Or is there a possibility to reference directly, like in Excel?

Comment: @Evgeniy this is the only way. `1I69LQ37hA5NjjJmuwmWkrDI_daiU_cnYDrUBpMm` - this part can be either ID of your sheet or whole URL of your sheet (just fyi)

Comment: The correct formula is `=VLOOKUP(A6,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOzV/","report!A:B"),2,0)`  - thank you!